# Can't mass-assign error with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

**Controller**

```
def update
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  @group_func = @group.functionalities
  @functionalities_all = Funcionalidade.all
  @func = params[:group][:update]

  unless @group_func.include?(@func) do
    @group_func << @func
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<div class="field">
    <% options = @functionalities_all.collect{|f| [f.name, f.id]} %>
    <%= f.select(:update, options, { :include_blank => true, :selected => nil}) %>
    <%= button_to "Add" %>
</div>
```

When I add a functionality to group Rails return this error:

> **ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in GruposController#update**
>
> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: update

and if I try to add :update to Model return this error:

> unknown attribute: update

Has anyone ever had a similar error?

Comment: Is the error still the same when replacing :update by another keyword?

Comment: Do you have `update` attribute as `attr_accessible` in `group.rb` (Group model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Group Model, add the following code.

```
attr_accessible :update
```

Rails naturally protects attributes from being assigned without being unprotected first.  `attr_accessible` unprotects them so you can modify them in your controller.  If you want all your attributes to be modifiable, add `attr_protected` to your model.

Comment: I've already added :update to model, but I receive the following error: "unknown attribute: update"

Comment: try this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease

Comment: np! Glad I could help you out!